# Sencha Touch 2 event: painted vs show?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a question regarding the `show` event.
in my application I'm handling the `painted` event of my panel like this:

```
Ext.define('mvcTest.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
    refs: {
            panel: '#testpanel'
    },
    control:{
                panel: {
                    painted: 'onPainted'        
                }
        }
    },
    onPainted: function(){
        alert('painted');
    }
});
```

the docu say's, that there is also a "show" event, but it get not fired at all:

```
Ext.define('mvcTest.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
    refs: {
            panel: '#testpanel'
    },
    control:{
                panel: {
                    show: 'onShow'        
                }
        }
    },
    onShow: function(comp, obj){
        alert('show');
    }
});
```

why this does not work?
i know, alerting is the wrong way, but that's not the question.
thanks,
mike

Comment: 1) have you included controller in you app.js?

Comment: yep, without that the first version would not work either

Comment: So 'painted' event is working, but 'show' is not?

Comment: Isn't show only fired when the show() method is called on the component ?

Comment: yes, painted is working fine!
i don't know, there is no info in the documentation when show is fired.

Comment: seems there's no mistake in your controller. I guess there should be something outthere in other places of your app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that there's no mistake in your controller. The key reason may lie in another part of your application but ... ok, according to my experience:

- `painted` event straight-forward. Everytime your view is really rendered on the screen, `painted` fired up. (Note: `painted` event fires BEFORE the child components of your view are totally rendered. In another word, `painted` first, DOM generation second.)
- `show` event does NOT necessarily fire up, especially for the initialization time of your view. `show` event is something fired up when you firstly somehow **hide** your view, and **show** it later.

Just experience, may be variant. But hope it might be helpful for you.

Comment: ok, the reason for this question: i want to do an ajax request when the view is shown to the user. the response is an json object which is the model for the view components. that means, painted is the way to go? show event: i thought that show is the default event when the component is shown to the user and all child components were totally rendered..

Comment: for `painted` event, you're right. For `show` event: as I've said, it fires when the view "change its state" from hidden to visible. So,  `show` (and even `painted`) event could be fired up when your view and child views are not completely rendered. Hope it's clear enough. ;)

Comment: ah, ok i see.. i analysed the html on "panel-switch". the panel will be hidden with "display: none". when i switch back, it is block, therefore the show event isn't fired. show event refers to css "visibility"?

Answer (score 6):

You **can't handle 'painted' event in controller**, because it is not bubbled up to it.

*From sencha docs:* This event is not available to be used with event delegation. Instead 'painted' only fires if you explicily add at least one listener to it, due to performance reason.
You can handle it by defining a listener in you panel.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  config: {
  },
  listeners: {
    painted: function (element, options) {
      console.log("I've painted");
    }
  }
});
```

But 'show' event can be handled in controller. Check if another part of your application see that controller.
(Have you provided reference to your controller? Is the id of your panel is right?)

Comment: ah ok, thanks. but why i can handle the painted event in my controller? the id of the panel is right, reference all seems to be right. the controller will initialize,...

Comment: it's off topic but: i need 15 reputation to make +1, or what do u mean with +1? ;)

Comment: maybe he totally agrees with this answer. Excuse me, but I do not, indeed. Because `painted`, in fact, IS available with event registration in controllers. To `show` event, it must be available, too. But the question is: **why `painted` worked but `show` did not?**

just comment. No -1 for your answer.

Comment: another thing, do NOT rely on ST2 documentation. It's foolish. Just gain exp from actual code lines.

Comment: From my experience, and the docs, and others commenting in the docs, `painted` is not available in controllers.

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to add this link [to the Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?233658-Too-many-events-avoid-painted-at-all-costs) where it is mentioned that painted is not listenable from controllers for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but someone might find it useful:
Sencha does not initially fire the event 'show' and 'painted'.
You need to trigger it initially.

Use this code snippet to listen to the events from the controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  config: {
  },
  listeners: {
    painted: function (element, options) {
      this.fireEvent('painted', [element, options])
    }
  }
});
```