# Show & Hide events for a Sencha Touch navigation view

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'd like to be able to hide and show certain buttons in a navigation view bar when a view is push and popped onto the view stack. Shame I can't control that from the view config itself (but I'll save that moan for another time).

I wanted to know which events I should be using when a view is push/popped on a navigation view.  The docs sometimes lie and I've been told many times not too trust it, so I'm not! Come on Sencha, Microsoft wouldn't get away with this!
So Any ideas?  When I try to print out all the events for a view I get very unreliable behaviour:

What I've found:
When I **push** a view I get:

```
initialize
hide
show
```

When I **pop** a view I get:

```
hide
show
```

What the flip is going on?!?

**The code to show events happening:**

```
 control: {           
            myViewRef: {                
                initialize: function() { console.log("initialize") },
                activated: function() { console.log("activated") },
                deactivated: function() { console.log("deactivated") },
                painted: function() { console.log("painted") },
                show: function() { console.log("show") },
                hide: function() { console.log("hide") }
            },
  }
```

**The code to actually push/pop a view:**

```
 onInBoxListViewItemTap: function(scope, index, item, record) {
        console.log("onInBoxListViewItemTap");

        var detailsView = this.getEnquiryDetailsViewRef();

        // push view
        var navview = this.getMyInboxViewRef();
        navview.push(detailsView);
    }
```

Does this stuff actually work properly i.e. Are there concrete events which are guaranteed to fire when a view is pushed and popped?

Comment: How do you push/pop view? Can you post a code where you create and show view?

Comment: Can you actually put sample app to jsfiddle or something like that? It's simply not enough information to help you.

Comment: I tried to add the code to a sencha fiddle, but now sencha fiddle is stuck/broken when I retried to load my example?!?  I now can't get back to my code! Maybe if someone can provide a simple example of buttons being unhidden and shown in a navigation bar as different views are pushed/popped this would help my greatly. That is my goal.

Comment: This was my fiddle to prove I tried;) but I can't access it :( http://www.senchafiddle.com/#fevpr. Any ideas.

Comment: Yea... You fiddle doesn't work. I will try to find some examples in my code but meanwhile - what exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to have standard 'Back' button functionality in navigation controller - I believe it's built-in and you don't have to do anything

Comment: No, imagine you have several views that are pushed. You want the views pushed to have different buttons in the bar. I can't control this in the config for each view. That is why I want to know when a view is popped/pushed so I can hide/unhide buttons.

Comment: What's your child view class? Is it Ext.Panel? Also what exact version of ST you're using?

Comment: ST2 - 2.1.0.  Views that are pushed are of type Ext.Container.

Comment: Take a look at my answer pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you have a typo in your code. You need to reference `activate` and `deactivate` not `activate_d` and `deactivate_d`.

Second, I would try to subscribe to `push` and `pop` events of navigation view and see if it would get you what you want.

Comment: Not sure about the activate_d and deactivate_d but the push/pop events were useful in the end. I hide and show depending on which view is being pushed/popped.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.I use painted handler to solve it.
You can't handle 'painted' event in controller
[the painted event description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873143/sencha-touch-2-event-painted-vs-show)